# sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL logs in working API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, heroku, pg-hba.conf

Heroku is hosting my node.js API and the PostgreSQL addon is responsible for my DB.

I recently upgraded my heroku db plan from hobby-dev to standard-0 and got some issues with SSL connection. After setting sslmode=require, my new DB was performing with no problems and I was really happy with it.

Suddenly, without any changes in code, nor in environment config vars and in a day with a reduced request flow, it started to print on PaperTrail the following error:

> [COBALT] [10-1] sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Even when my node.js API is not requested, this error gets printed. I'm intrigued with the credentials **user "postgres", database "postgres"**, my DB in which the API stores requests, responses and some useful data has other credentials.

The API is working fine, but these logs are really pissing me off and I have no idea what is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something probably was changed after all. This is the general purpose "cannot connect" message. Look into the PostgreSQL log file for details.

Answer (score 2):

For those that land here from seeing this log message -- [FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres).

Comment: Also see https://help.heroku.com/MDM23G46/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-i-upgrade-to-pg-8

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely green. I just started coding 5 months ago. While working on a school assignment, I encountered the same issue. Near identical situation to that outlined in the OP. I ended up finding my solution. I found a spelling error in my code here. But It seems that error is related to ssl.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(CONNECTION_STRING, {
    dialect:"postgres", 
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
})
```